# List created outside of for loop forgotten by python when I .append()

Tags: string, list, for-loop, append

I am trying to iterate through a string and write characters to a list (with a 'for' loop). If I create the empty list before the for loop, python thinks its a string when I get to myList.append(stuff) It works if I create the empty list in the loop, but the obviously it gets erased at each iteration. I've tried to play with global stuff but I'm not getting anywhere. *This is supposed to be a very simply cipher, a warm-up to a bigger project but this is holding me up.

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
while True:
    code = []
    index = int(input("Code Index:"))
    message = input("Message: ")
    for i in message:
        if i in alphabet:
            value = alphabet.find(i)
            value += index
            new_letter = alphabet[value]
            print('new letter: ' + new_letter)
            code.append(new_letter)
            print('code: ' + str(code))
        else:
            code.append(i)
        code = ''.join(code)
    input("EXPORT CODE: ")
    print(code)
```

But when this runs I get:

```
<i>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Max Hayes/Desktop/PyCrypt/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    code.append(new_letter)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'</i>
```

Comment: After days thinking I was going crazy (but within an hour of posting) I have realized my simple mistake:

I assumed the error was thrown right away, but actually the loop works fine during the first iteration.

At the end of the loop I change 'code' from a list to a string with:

`code = ''join.(code)`

Because of this, on the second iteration when i try to `code.append()` it does not work because 'code' is now a string. *And I thought I was saving time not creating a new variable*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`code = ''.join(code)` you rebind `code` to a str class, that's why you have the problem. Probably you can change it to `code_str = ''.join(code)` . In addition, this statement need to be put outside of the `for` loop.